# Are questions about Android Studio settings on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Do questions about Android Studio plugins, or settings fit into the scope of Stack Overflow?

I've come across a couple of questions regarding [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) add-ons that were received well, but they're also somewhat older.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [What is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page:

> ...
>
> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
>
> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Now Android Studio is a tool commonly used by progammers so questions about that tool and how to configure and use it are on-topic. That same reasoning can apply to plugins for that tool.

It is key in these kind of cases to make clear what problem unique to software development you're trying to solve with the tool and/or plugin.

Keep in mind that asking us directly to find you a plugin that meet certain requirements is still off-topic under this close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This is easily circumvented by describing your context and the problem you're facing with your current tool setup. Answers can then either elaborate on a work-around or offer alternatives not limited to plugins, tools or other off-site resources.